# MySQL INSERT SELECT on large static table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to copy the content of one table to another. So I started using:

```
INSERT new_table SELECT * FROM old_table
```

However, I am getting the following error now:

```
1297, "Got temporary error 233 'Out of operation records in transaction coordinator (increase MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations)' from NDBCLUSTER"
```

I think I have an understanding why this occurs: My table is huge, and MySQL tries to take a snapshot in time (lock everything and make one large transaction out of it).

However, my data is fairly static and there is no other concurrent session that would modify the data. How can I tell MySQL to copy one row at a time, or in smaller chunks, without locking the whole thing?

Edit note: I already know that I can just read the whole table row-by-row into memory/file/dump and write back. I am interested to know if there is an easy way (maybe setting isolation level?). Note that the engine is InnoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Data Migration is one of the few instances where a [CURSOR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html) can make sense, as you say, to ensure that the number of locks stays sane.

Use a cursor in conjunction with [TRANSACTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html), where you commit after every row, or after N rows (e.g. use a counter with modulo)

Comment: Thanks. This sounds interesting. Can you provide an example SQL procedure or command on how I would do it?

Answer (score 0):

select the data from innodb into an outfile and load infile into
cluster